# What is the rationale for as.logical double coercion?

Tags: r, boolean

I'm trying to understand the coercion rationale for doubles:

```
as.logical(c(-1, -0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.1,1:10))
#>  [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [12]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I can see that coercion happens on a scalar (sign doesn't matter) and
that only exactly 0 is coerced to `FALSE`. I was surprised by this,
there seems to be no notion of "closest to..." or rounding to 0L or 1L.
I'm curious as to why.

I did try to hunt around for insight
[here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=as.logical)
but no success.

I also looked at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681166/what-evaluates-to-true-false-in-r).

Can someone explain why I should expect each of the above tested values
to coerce as they do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess would be that this is inherited from C, e.g. from [here](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_37.htm):

> In C true is represented by any numeric value not equal to 0 and false is represented by 0

Also see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104225/has-true-always-had-a-non-zero-value); at the moment I can't find a better source for the official language specification.

A pirated copy of Kernighan and Ritchie 2d ed. I found online (I'd rather not link to it) says on p. 50, Section 3.2, "If-Else" (emphasis added):

> The expression is evaluated; if it is true (**that is, if expression has a non-zero value**), statement 1 is executed. If it is false (**expression is zero**) and if there is an else  part,  statement 2  is executed instead.

@hrbrmstr points out that the R internal definition of LOGICAL that's used for the conversion is in `Rinternals.h:`

```
#define LOGICAL(x) ((int *) DATAPTR(x))
```

Comment: I suppose the question then becomes why this was the rationale when defined in `C`!